# Can't pair my HUAWEI Bluetooth Mouse with Ubuntu LTS 20.04.1

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

So I click on Settings>Bluetooth and then I select my mouse ("HUAWEI Mouse"). Before that I am putting my mouse in pairing mode aswell. It says "not set up" so I click on my mouse, it loads, and after not even 1 second it says "not set up" again.

Comment: Are you using any USB bluetooth adapter? If yes, what's the name and model of USB bluetooth adapter?

Comment: Hi, no I‘m not using any bluetooth adapter.

Comment: So I assume that you have a laptop. What's the laptop name and model? What is the model number of your bluetooth mouse? Please [edit] the question and add the details.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same mouse and the exact same problem. I've tried a few solutions but no luck on my end here's whats worked for other people with Bluetooth mice:

```
$ bluetoothctl
$ scan on
$ scan off
$ devices
$ pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
$ connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
$ trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

And there's also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p) solution if you're dual-booting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this bug on Huawei Matebook laptops (or if you use Realtek RTL8822CE bluetooth adapter device id 1358:c123), check out this link:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bluez/+bug/1887968

TL;DR: this will be fixed in kernel 5.11

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the linux kernel to version 5.11

Here is a tutorial that helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImqsMbjOvsU&ab_channel=Installingprogramsonlinux

Note: In case you cannot login with kernel 5.11 you will have to disable the secure boot option in UEFI.

I leave one more tutorial on how to disable the secure boot option: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsCyZlLgrUY&ab_channel=BoostUpStation